# Holonomic distributions in the analytic setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schwartz-distributions, d-modules, real-analytic-structures, analytic-d-modules

We are interested in a reference to the notion of Holonomic distributions in the real analytic setting. Namely, distributions that generate a Holonomic D-module under the action of the algebra of differential operators with analytic coefficients. We are  interested in distributions on
$\mathbb R^n$ or, more generally, distributions on the set or real points of a  complex analytic manifold with a real structure.

We found a  discussion of regular holonomic distributions in the analytic setting in the book:

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-0717-6

It seems that what we need is completely analogous and even simpler, however we did not find a reference.

The main non-trivial statement that we need is that a proper direct image of holonomic distribution in this sense is holonomic.

Comment: So far as I understand, the theory of D-modules requires at minimum a real analytic manifold. Is that alright for your purposes? Anyway, what is your definition of the proper direct image of a holonomic distribution? It's certainly true (and standard) that the proper direct image of a holonomic *module* is holonomic.